# PHP conditional string replacement

Tags: php, regex, string

I'm trying to replace the `~` into `|` between the `[` `]` in the folowwing case:

```
{stackoverflow is a [cool~great~fast] website ~ Find your answers [easily~quickly] on stackoverflow}.
```

Note: The text between the `[` `]` can be multiline.

I've tried multiple regexs buth with no luck.

My closest call at the moment is:

```
$text = preg_replace("/\[(.*?)~(.*?)\]/i", "[$1|$2]", $text);
```

But that returns

```
{stackoverflow is a [cool~great|fast] website ~ Find your answers [easily|quickly] on stackoverflow}.
```

Comment: You should report which regular expressions you tried. It could be you make a mistake, and the regular expression is not correct.

Comment: The brackets can not be nested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use one regex to find all strings in brackets and then another to replace the `~`s in them. You can use `preg_replace_callback` to apply the `~`-replacing regex to all the substrings in brackets like this:

```
preg_replace_callback('/\[[^\]]+\]/', function ($str) {
    return str_replace('~', '|', $str[0]);
}, $my_string)
```

Comment: I would use str_replace instead of preg_replace in the callback, as invoking any preg function is fairly costly, so you could use str_replace('~', '|', $str[0]) instead and get the same effect.

Comment: @tsgrasser: Fair enough. Done.

Answer (score 2):

simpler than you think

```
 echo preg_replace('/~(?=[^\[\]]*\])/s', '|', $a);
```

?= is a [lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and reads "followed by". That is, "a tilde followed by some non-brackets and then a closing bracket" - this matches only ~'s inside [ ]

Comment: This would also replace the ~ in "~la]", i.e. it does not require an opening bracket to occur before the tilde. That's probably not a problem though, so +1.

Answer (score 0):

What are some examples of the regexes you've used? My immediate thought is that [] is tripping you up because that is used to match character classes. If you want to match [ or ] as a literal you must escape it with backslashes: \[ or \].

Comment: My closest call was preg_replace("/\[(.*?)~(.*?)\]/i", "[\1|\2]", $text);

But I'm getting a weird character instead of the text.

Comment: the [] are escaped but stackoverflow removes the \ before it for some reason.

Comment: @brechtvhb: You get the funny character because `\1` and `\2` mean different things in double quotes than in single quotes. If I use single quotes and escape the brackets, I get correct results for simple cases with your regex. However it does not work when there are multiple `~`s inside the brackets (only the first one in each bracket-pair will be replaced).