# preg_replace when pattern NOT followed

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Using `preg_replace`, I would like to replace all instances of a "pipe not followed by `http://`", If the pipe is followed by `http://`, then do nothing. For example,

The following string:

```
http://www.xyz.org/docs/pdfs/2014/file_name_1.pdf|file_name_2.pdf|http://www.xyz.org/docs/pdfs/2014/file_name_3.pdf|
```

Once run thru preg_replace will become:

```
http://www.xyz.org/docs/pdfs/2014/file_name_1.pdf|http://www.xyz.org/docs/pdfs/2014/file_name_2.pdf|http://www.xyz.org/docs/pdfs/2014/file_name_3.pdf|
```

The code I have in place so far replaces all pipes.

```
$string = trim(preg_replace("/\|\|+/", "|", $string));
$string = str_replace("|", "|http://www.xyz.org/docs/pdfs/2014/", $string);
```

Comment: [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173087/php-conditional-string-replacement
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19848516/replace-string-on-condition-php
  [3]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10941490/php-conditional-string-replacement-str-replace


check these links

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you simply need to use a 'negative lookahead'...

CODE:

```
<?php
   $a = 'http://www.xyz.org/docs/pdfs/2014/file_name_1.pdf|file_name_2.pdf|http://www.xyz.org/docs/pdfs/2014/file_name_3.pdf|';
   $b = preg_replace("/\|(?!http:\/\/)/",'|http://www.xyz.org/docs/pdfs/2014/',$a);
   echo 'A: '.$a."\n";
   echo 'B: '.$b."\n";
?>
```

This regular expression **`\|(?!http:\/\/)`** will match...

- **`\|`** a vertical bar
- **`(?!http:\/\/)`** not followed by http:// (this is the negative lookahead zero width assertion)

OUTPUT:

```
> A: http://www.xyz.org/docs/pdfs/2014/file_name_1.pdf|file_name_2.pdf|http://www.xyz.org/docs/pdfs/2014/file_name_3.pdf|
> B: http://www.xyz.org/docs/pdfs/2014/file_name_1.pdf|http://www.xyz.org/docs/pdfs/2014/file_name_2.pdf|http://www.xyz.org/docs/pdfs/2014/file_name_3.pdf|http://www.xyz.org/docs/pdfs/2014/
```

This is a simplified example which also replaces the last trailing '|' in your string, but you get the idea of the regex.
If needed you could handle the trailing bar with this variation of the regex `/\|(?!(http:\/\/|$))/` which uses the lookahead to check for end of string too.

Comment: Thanks. Your example removes file_name_2.pdf from the string altogether, where as I need 'http://www.xyz.org/docs/pdfs/2014/' inserted before the file name.

Comment: I realised that and was correcting my reply as you posted :-)

Comment: Thanks. I tested yours and it works properly. The remaining issue is that it converts the last pipe with the URL, would prefer the last pipe be stripped from the string. I have tried to make that work but I keep messing up the other aspects.

Comment: Doesn't the alternative regex given in the last sentence handle the trailing pipe? `/\|(?!(http:\/\/|$))/` I think it should leave the pipe unreplaced as per the desired result you gave in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe by using explode and test one by one

```
$string = 'http://www.xyz.org/docs/pdfs/2014/file_name_1.pdf|file_name_2.pdf|http://www.xyz.org/docs/pdfs/2014/file_name_3.pdf|';
$string = addHttp($string); 

function addHttp($string) {
    $a_string = explode('|', $string);
    $return_string = '';
    foreach($a_string as $a_s) {
        if(trim($a_s) == '')
            continue; 

        if(preg_match('#^http://#', $a_s))
            $return_string .= $a_s.'|';
        else
            $return_string .= 'http://'.$a_s.'|';
    }

    return $return_string;
}
```

EDIT : I changed strpos by preg_match

Comment: I did not think of using an explode. Thank you, that works and I am progressing nicely.

Comment: This works, but you're doing a lot of unnecessary work.  `preg_replace()` is perfect for this job, as [Gavin's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21260099/20938) demonstrates.